# how to apply joins in spark scala when we have multiple values in the join column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data in two text files as

```
file 1:(patient id,diagnosis code)
+----------+-------+
|patient_id|diag_cd|
+----------+-------+
|         1|  y,t,k|
|         2|  u,t,p|
|         3|  u,t,k|
|         4|  f,o,k|
|         5|  e,o,u|
+----------+-------+

file2(diagnosis code,diagnosis description) Time T1
+-------+---------+
|diag_cd|diag_desc|
+-------+---------+
|      y|      yen|
|      t|      ten|
|      k|      ken|
|      u|      uen|
|      p|      pen|
|      f|      fen|
|      o|      oen|
|      e|      een|
+-------+---------+
```

data in file 2 is not fixed and keeps on changing, means at any given point of time diagnosis code y can have diagnosis description as yen and at other point of time it can have diagnosis description as ten. For example below

```
file2 at Time T2
+-------+---------+
|diag_cd|diag_desc|
+-------+---------+
|      y|      ten|
|      t|      yen|
|      k|      uen|
|      u|      oen|
|      p|      ken|
|      f|      pen|
|      o|      een|
|      e|      fen|
+-------+---------+
```

I have to read these two files data in spark and want only those patients id who are diagnosed with uen.
it can be done using spark sql or scala both.

I tried to read the file1 in spark-shell. The two columns in file1 are pipe delimited.

```
scala> val tes1 = sc.textFile("file1.txt").map(x => x.split('|')).filter(y => y(1).contains("u")).collect
tes1: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(2, u,t,p), Array(3, u,t,k), Array(5, e,o,u))
```

But as the diagnosis code related to a diagnosis description is not constant in file2 so will have to use the join condition. But I dont know how to apply joins when the diag_cd column in file1 has multiple values.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: my approach is I am reading both the files and converting it to dataset  scala> val tes1 = sc.textFile("file1.txt").map(x => x.split('|')).map(y => (y(0),y(1).split(","))).toDS      and scala> val tes2 = sc.textFile("file2").map(x => (x.split(",")(0),x.split(",")(1))).toDS    now I am using map function to replace diagnosis code in tes1 with diagnosis description in tes2  but have issues with the syntaxes  val tes3 = tes2.map(x => (tes1.map(y => if (y._2.contains(x._1) y.updated(x._2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the answer below

//Read the file1 into a dataframe

```
val file1DF = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter","|")
.option("header",true)
.load("file1PATH")
```

//Read the file2 into a dataframe

```
val file2DF = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter","|")
.option("header",true)
.load("file2path")
```

//get the patient id dataframe for the diag_desc as uen

```
file1DF.join(file2DF,file1DF.col("diag_cd").contains(file2DF.col("diag_cd")),"inner")
.filter(file2DF.col("diag_desc") === "uen")
.select("patient_id").show
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the table t1 from format1 to format2 using explode method.

   Format1:

   ```
   file 1:(patient id,diagnosis code)
   +----------+-------+
   |patient_id|diag_cd|
   +----------+-------+
   |         1|  y,t,k|
   |         2|  u,t,p|
   +----------+-------+
   ```

   to

   ```
   file 1:(patient id,diagnosis code)
   +----------+-------+
   |patient_id|diag_cd|
   +----------+-------+
   |         1|  y    |
   |         1|  t    |
   |         1|  k    |
   |         2|  u    |
   |         2|  t    |
   |         2|  p    |
   +----------+-------+
   ```

   Code:

   ```
   scala> val data = Seq("1|y,t,k", "2|u,t,p")
   data: Seq[String] = List(1|y,t,k, 2|u,t,p)

   scala> val df1 = sc.parallelize(data).toDF("c1").withColumn("patient_id", split(col("c1"), "\\|").getItem(0)).withColumn("col2", split(col("c1"), "\\|").getItem(1)).select("patient_id", "col2").withColumn("diag_cd", explode(split($"col2", "\\,"))).select("patient_id", "diag_cd")
   df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [patient_id: string, diag_cd: string]

   scala> df1.collect()
   res4: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([1,y], [1,t], [1,k], [2,u], [2,t], [2,p])
   ```

   I have created dummy data here for illustration. Note how we are exploding the particular column above using

   ```
   scala> val df1 = sc.parallelize(data).toDF("c1").
    | withColumn("patient_id", split(col("c1"), "\\|").getItem(0)).
    | withColumn("col2", split(col("c1"), "\\|").getItem(1)).
    | select("patient_id", "col2").
    | withColumn("diag_cd", explode(split($"col2", "\\,"))).
    | select("patient_id", "diag_cd")
   ```

   df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [patient_id: string, diag_cd: string]
2. Now you can create df2 for file 2 using -

   ```
   scala> val df2 = sc.textFile("file2.txt").map(x => (x.split(",")(0),x.split(",")(1))).toDF("diag_cd", "diag_desc")
   df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [diag_cd: string, diag_desc: string]
   ```
3. Join df1 with df2 and filter as per the requirement.

   ```
   df1.join(df2, df1.col("diag_cd") === df2.col("diag_cd")).filter(df2.col("diag_desc") === "ten").select(df1.col("patient_id")).collect()
   ```